# How to apply CSS3 transforms with keyframe animations ?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transforms

How to apply more than one transform with CSS3 animation ?

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="cell"><span class="inner"></span><span class="inner"></span></div>
<div class="cell"><span class="inner"></span><span class="inner"></span></div>
<div class="cell"><span class="inner"></span><span class="inner"></span></div>
<div class="cell"><span class="inner"></span><span class="inner"></span></div>
<div class="cell"><span class="inner"></span><span class="inner"></span></div>
</div>
```

And my attempt :

```
@-webkit-keyframes firstanim{
    from{
        -webkit-transform:scale(1);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    backgroud:skyblue;
    left:0px;

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }    to{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    background:orange;
    left:100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
   }
}


.container{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:20px;
    width:250px;
    height:50px;
    position:realtive;
}
.cell{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;

    background:skyblue;

    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px 5px;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation: firstanim 3s infinite;

}
.inner{
 width:100%;
 height:50%;
 float:left;

    border:1px solid white;
    border-left-width:0px;
    borer-right-width:0px;
}
```

The result is located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TBrf2/1/).

Only one transform is being applied to the elements, even if I add more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TBrf2/3/) working with multiple transforms.

```
-webkit-transform:scale(1)  rotateY(0deg);
```

you need to apply like this.

Comment: Please don't post an answer that's identical to another answer, especially if the other answer is more detailed. It doesn't add any contribution.

Comment: sorry! I didnt saw the answer due to upadating fiddle

Answer (score 5):

If you write something like this:

```
transform: rotate(30deg);
transform: scale(3);
```

then *the second one overrides the first one* and your element is only scaled, not rotated.

In order to apply multiple transforms to a single element you need to chain them.

Example:

```
transform: rotate(30deg) scale(3) translateX(3em) skewY(60deg);
```

Also, **the order in which you apply them matters** and you may get different results depending on the chosen order - see [**this example**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3799448), where the blue box doesn't have the same shape as the red one after applying the same two transforms, but in inverse order.

Your fiddle with chained transforms: http://jsfiddle.net/TBrf2/4/